# Friend function for class in dll

Tags: c++, dll, friend

Lets say I have the following class in my dll

`class Test { private: int x; };`

and following function in client side application which uses my dll

`void test();`

Is there a way to make test function friend for Test class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make test function friend for Test class?

Yes, add a `friend` declaration to the class definition:

```
class Test {
private:
    int x;
    friend void test();
};
```

Comment: Let me clarify something. Does this mean that if I make test function friend for Test class by adding "friend void test();" in class then anyone else who uses my dll can implement a function named test and thereby access the x variable?

Comment: @ArthurTsaturyan Yes, that's correct.

Comment: This is pretty amazing. Тhank you!

Comment: @ArthurTsaturyan You're welcome!